# Named events -- catch-all or specific?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm developing client- and server-apps (node.js, socket.io for communication). Messages sent between the client and server have many different types, and I'd originally thought to include the type in the transmitted object:

```
// Client
var data = {
  "type" : 5,
  "message" : "Hello, world!"
};
socket.emit("generic_event", data);
```

On the server side, this would be handled as such:

```
// Server
socket.on("generic_event", function(e){
  console.log("Got a generic_event!", e.type);
});
```

However, there is also the possibility of being more specific with event types, e.g.:

```
// Client
socket.emit(data.type, data);
// Server
socket.on(1, function(){
  console.log("We got '1'!");
});
// Elsewhere on in the server...
socket.on(5, function(){
  console.log("We got '5'!");
});
```

I'm curious to know what the benefits are of following scheme A (single generic / catch-all event) vs. scheme B (multiple/many specific named events). Performance? Personal coding style? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mostly a matter of preference, as the message is sent to the client either way. However, handling each event separately is cleaner in the case you want to receive acknowledgement from the client, and neither would you have to perform an `if/else` or `switch` to decide what to do with data.

This is an example of client code that notifies the server when the event has fired.

```
socket.on('event', function(fn) {
  fn();
});
```

However, if you sent type in an object, you would still only have one callback. You'd then have to define the type of response the client is going to send to the server in the callback. So that would be the difference between this:

```
socket.on('foo', function(data, fn) {
  // foo data
  fn();
});

socket.on('bar', function(data, fn) {
  // bar data
  fn();
});
```

And this:

```
socket.on('event', function(data, fn) {
  var res = {};
  // data of undefined type
  if (data.property == 'a_condition') {
    res.type = 'type1';
    res.data = 'foo';
  }
  else if (data.property == 'a_condition') {
    res.type = 'type2';
    res.data = 'bar';
  }
  fn(res);
});
```

So all in all, it is a matter of personal preference, as regardless of method, there will be data sent from the server to the client, and there will be an event fired client side. I would suggest specific handlers for events because it is less messy and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It makes sense to code to this style in both the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `socket.io-events` on npm

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var router = require('socket.io-events')();
router.on('*', function (sock, args, next) {
  var name = args.shift(), msg = args.shift();
  sock.emit('received event', name, msg);
});
io.use(router);
```